# Props or blocks?

Tags: hammer, garrys-mod

I was wondering what would be best if I was to create a really big map with many items or decorations. Currently I'm working on a library for a GMod/Garry's Mod Server and I wanted to add a lot of shelves. Perhaps with a variety of different looking shelves like one shelf with red books another one with yellow and another one with blue and green and some with everything mixed together.

So I was wondering what would be the best for the performance. I mean many small objects usually tend to need a lot of rendering but if it's best to set a model as `prop_static` that would also be great.

The other shelves I found are all `prop_dynamics` or `prop_physic` but `prop_static` would be good enough for me.

The main question is "What's best, (in regards of server performance) Prop or Block?"

Comment: Did you try setting up a test map with a large number of each to measure the performance difference?

Comment: Thank you for at least giving an idea. Yes I indead had some form of a testmap but the thing is, that the whole map will be a hugh map and I was just working on a library for it with about 7 lines of bookshelf with 7 shelfs per line and each shelf had 10 blocks. So about 490 blocks only for shelfs. I expanded with second floor 2nd and 3rd room so I would have at the very least about 1500 blocks just for the bookshelf. However I found out that if I set the shelfs to func_detail, that it could help a lot with the performance since those are only loaded if they are about to be seen or visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the func_detail for many blocks help with the performance and compiling time.
Check here for more:
https://www.reddit.com/r/hammer/comments/3gdjxv/portal_flow_vvis_taking_forever/
http://www.tophattwaffle.com/hammer-tutorial-v2-series-6-basic-optimization/
https://www.tophattwaffle.com/hammer-tutorial-v2-series-21-optimization/